# p5js pass an array of x y coordinates to ellipse function

Tags: javascript, arrays, p5.js

in p5js you can draw a circle using `ellipse(100,100,20)` - is it possible to pass an array of `[100,100,20]` to the ellipse function?

this doesn't work:

```js
var arr = [100,100,20];
ellipse((...arr));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why the double parentheses? Spread operator inside the double parentheses causes a syntax error.

<s>`ellipse((...arr));`</s>

```js
ellipse(...arr);
```